# How can I add applications.properties into a Component in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 14 and I want to include these into a Component class for Spring Boot.

```
# Database
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=CET
spring.datasource.username=myUser
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
```

I want to make it looks like this. Here I can include the class `FTPConnection` with `@Autowired` in a `view` and then change it when ever I want.

But these are imported with `@PropertySource("classpath:ftp.properties")` and `applications.properties` is not. So how can I change e.g `spring.security.user.name=myUser` on the fly? Do I need to create a `Component` class or something?

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:ftp.properties")
public class FTPConnection {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Value("${ftp.connectionPath}")
    private String connectionPath; // e.g ftp.example.org/folder/path
    
    @Value("${ftp.password}")
    private String password;
    
    @Value("${ftp.username}")
    private String username;
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly reference `application.properties` as
springboot picks it up anyway (of unless you are talking about a file
with that name but located somewhere else). `@Value(...)` should work
with values from `application.properties` (or any other sources e.g.
envvars or via profiles).

Comment: @cfrick I have always use an `application.properties` when it comes to database decleration. Right now I want to create a Component class where I create the database connection there. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Remove the `@PropertySource` from your example, change the `@Value` to the values you want to inject (or even better, check if spring has some DatasourceConfiguration or DatasourceProperties class). Then you can deal with creating your connection in the @PostConstruct or whatever seems appropriate. Other than that it would help if you would show your actual problem and the failing code and the errors you get.

Comment: You mean by "Component class" an own project that produces a JAR?